# Click event not triggering on after-added spans

Tags: jquery, events, click, html

This code isn't working as expected:

```
    function makeToken()
    {
    var $span = $("<span>new</span>");

    $span.bind('click',function(){
        alert('test');
    })


    return $span;
}

$('h1, #content p, #content h2').after(makeToken());
```

Span elements will appear after all these elements ('h1, #content p, #content h2') but when I click the spans the click event isn't triggered. Why not? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clone of the `<span>` element you created is appended. It should do a `.clone(true)` so the handlers are cloned as well.

Looks like a bug, but seems to be fixed in `jQuery 1.5`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7PUew/1/

You could use event delegation instead of direct binding, but more information would be needed to know the best approach.

Comment: Not sure but you might need to add the element to the document before trying to bind events to it or you could use live() as suggested in the other answer, that will auto bind any new matches.

Comment: @David: You can bind handlers before the elements are added (see my example above). And `.live()` doesn't auto bind to new elements. It uses document-wide event delegation. IMO, delegation is better used on local regions of the page, which is part of the reason I never use `.live()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `live()` instead of  `bind()`.